# R leaflet search marker NOT work

Tags: r, search, leaflet, markers

I was able to use these 2 packages to search the markers on the map. However, I just installed them on my new computer again, but the search button does not work now. How to search markers?
Thank you

```
# We need latest leaflet package from Github, as CRAN package is too old.
devtools::install_github('rstudio/leaflet')
devtools::install_github('bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras')
library("leaflet")
library("leaflet.extras")

cities <- read.csv(textConnection("
City,Lat,Long,Pop
                              Boston,42.3601,-71.0589,645966
                              Hartford,41.7627,-72.6743,125017
                              New York City,40.7127,-74.0059,8406000
                              Philadelphia,39.9500,-75.1667,1553000
                              Pittsburgh,40.4397,-79.9764,305841
                              Providence,41.8236,-71.4222,177994
                              "))

leaflet(cities) %>% addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>%
addCircleMarkers(lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat, weight = 1, fillOpacity=0.5,
               radius = ~sqrt(Pop)/50 , popup = ~City, label=~City, group 
='cities') %>%
addResetMapButton() %>%
addSearchFeatures(
targetGroups = 'cities',
options = searchFeaturesOptions(
  zoom=12, openPopup = TRUE, firstTipSubmit = TRUE,
  autoCollapse = TRUE, hideMarkerOnCollapse = TRUE )) %>%
addControl("<P><B>Hint!</B> Search for ...<br/><ul><li>New York</li> 
<li>Boston</li><li>Hartford</li><li>Philadelphia</li><li>Pittsburgh</li> 
<li>Providence</li></ul></P>",
         position='bottomright')
```

[image: SS of Search Bar]

Comment: Could you make a [mcve] that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue using the same example you provided. I was able to figure out that, for some reason, `addSearchFeatures()` will NOT work with `addCircleMarkers()`, but it does work with `addMarkers()`. So I used a workaround that essentially plots the same data twice: the first time using `addCircleMarkers()` with your desired formatting settings and the second time using `addMarkers()` with a custom icon that is so small you cannot see it on the map. The key is to assign each to the appropriate `group`. The search bar will search the "invisible" Markers layer but the "CircleMarkers" will be the ones that appear on your map.

```
# using the same reproducible data from the question/example
cities <- read.csv(
    textConnection("City,Lat,Long,Pop
                    Boston,42.3601,-71.0589,645966
                    Hartford,41.7627,-72.6743,125017
                    New York City,40.7127,-74.0059,8406000
                    Philadelphia,39.9500,-75.1667,1553000
                    Pittsburgh,40.4397,-79.9764,305841
                    Providence,41.8236,-71.4222,177994
                    "))


leaflet(cities) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>%
  # these markers will appear on your map:
  addCircleMarkers(
     lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat, weight = 1, fillOpacity = 0.5,
     radius = ~sqrt(Pop)/50, popup = ~City, label = ~City, 
     group ='circles' # group needs to be different than addMarkers()
  ) %>%
  addResetMapButton() %>%
  # these markers will be "invisible" on the map:
  addMarkers(
    data = cities, lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat, label = cities$City,
    group = 'cities', # this is the group to use in addSearchFeatures()
    # make custom icon that is so small you can't see it:
    icon = makeIcon( 
      iconUrl = "http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png",
      iconWidth = 1, iconHeight = 1
    )
  ) %>%
  addSearchFeatures(
    targetGroups = 'cities', # group should match addMarkers() group
    options = searchFeaturesOptions(
      zoom=12, openPopup = TRUE, firstTipSubmit = TRUE,
      autoCollapse = TRUE, hideMarkerOnCollapse = TRUE
    )
  ) %>%
addControl("<P><B>Hint!</B> Search for ...<br/><ul><li>New York</li>
           <li>Boston</li><li>Hartford</li><li>Philadelphia</li><li>Pittsburgh</li>
           <li>Providence</li></ul></P>",
           position = 'bottomright'
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue, and found a solution on the `leaflet.extras` [Github issues page](https://github.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras/issues/143).

In your installation of `leaflet.extras`:

> Open lfx-search-prod.js and search for "e instanceof t.Path ||" , and then delete it and save the file. Your CircleMarker search should work now

This should allow you to use `addSearchFeature()` with `addCircleMarkers()` without any workaround now.

Comment: Unfortunately, `leaflet.extras` doesn't seem to be mainatined anymore as pointed out in their readme file. Do you happen to know an alternative soltuion?